Unable to receive messages on whatsapp from Twilio sandbox
I am trying to build a reminder application using Twilio Sandbox, in an order to receive messages you need to send "join dirt-or" to Twilio.
It works fine at first but after some time I need to send "join dirt-or" again in an order to receive messages.

I expected to receive the messages just after sending this "join dirt-or" thing one time. But I need to send this again and again in an order to receive the messages.
What could be the problem and how do I solve this?

In your scenario, the observed behavior is correct due to the WhatsApp 24-hour session policy. Since more than 24 hours have passed between your messages, a new session window must be initiated, which is why you need to send the "join sandbox" message once more. This limitation is specific to the Twilio Sandbox environment, which is intended primarily for development purposes.
If you were using your own WhatsApp sender, you could send a pre-approved content template message outside of the 24-hour window. Therefore, the solution would be to transition to your own WhatsApp sender instead of the sandbox for production use.
